# Define OSGB36 via OSTN15 in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, united-kingdom

I need to transform data (XYZ) from OSGB36 (15) to HS2 Snake Grid (EPSG:9300), but I am unable to define OSGB36(15) in ArcGIS Pro. I try to transform data using OSGB36 but I didn`t receive the correct data in HS2 Snake Grid.

Any idea where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Pro 2.9.2 includes NTv2 files for the geodetic transformations for HS2 Survey Grid (EPSG:9300 - HS2TN15) and OS National Grid (EPSG:27700 - OSTN15) **if** you install the ‘coordinate system’ data package on top.  This should be available from ESRI - e.g.:

[image: installer]

Correct transformations can then be configured within the software for converting between coordinate systems and using 'on the fly' reprojection.

Please note that OSTN15 NTv2 is an emulation of the authoritative version of OSTN15 and minor differences in coordinates may result. (The [Grid Inquest II](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/tools-support/os-net/transformation) software features the authoritative version of OSTN15).

Test point for checking conversions:

[image]